# Find the ports used by processes of a different machine

Tags: networking, process, ports

Is there a way to find the processes running on ports of a different machine?

Comment: Yes, ssh into it.

Comment: You need to give more context in order for us to help you.

Comment: I'd second @Doezer .. we would require information such as whether the PCs are on WORKGROUP or DOMAIN network? are they Windows or linux based... etc.